# Reporting account merger problem

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I entered SE with 2 emails. Then I informed the system that these two emails are mine. The system merged created accounts with the emails automatically. Now I cannot undelete [one of my previous posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300376/is-overlined-subseteq-d-circ-d-in-a-uniform-space/350024):

[image]

in this picture user61136 is me. when I clicked undelete, it was considered as an undelete vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened here is that the *post* is moved over in a merge, but the way we store delete vote user info isn't really ideal for moving over - it'd be crazy to say the least, so we don't really cover this edge case.